# Group and count by 16 hours time interval not working

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the number of records for a 16 hour time interval. Below is the code that I am using now.

```
;With Cte_hours as ( --hours generation
    Select top(6) hr = (Row_number() over (order by (Select NULL))-1)*4 from master..spt_values 
), cte2 as ( --getting range
    Select DateAdd(HH, c.hr, Convert(datetime,d.dts) ) as Dts_Start, DateAdd(MS, -2, DateAdd(HH, c.hr+ 4, Convert(datetime,d.dts) ) ) Dts_end
    from (select distinct convert(date, dt) as dts from TEST2 ) d
    cross apply Cte_hours c
) --actual query
Select c2.Dts_Start as DT, Sum(case when t.Dt is not null then 1 else 0 end) No_of_records,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M
from cte2 c2
Left Join TEST2 t
on t.Dt between c2.Dts_Start and c2.Dts_end
group by c2.Dts_Start,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M
order by LD_VOY_N, LD_VSL_M, Dts_Start ASC
```

This code is able to count the number of records I have based on a 4,6, and 12 hour interval. However, if I try to count based on a 16 hour interval, it somehow does not work. Below is my code and output that I used for the 16 hour interval.

```
;With Cte_hours as ( --hours generation
    Select top(6) hr = (Row_number() over (order by (Select NULL))-1)*16 from master..spt_values 
), cte2 as ( --getting range
    Select DateAdd(HH, c.hr, Convert(datetime,d.dts) ) as Dts_Start, DateAdd(MS, -2, DateAdd(HH, c.hr+ 16, Convert(datetime,d.dts) ) ) Dts_end
    from (select distinct convert(date, dt) as dts from TEST2 ) d
    cross apply Cte_hours c
) --actual query
Select c2.Dts_Start as DT, Sum(case when t.Dt is not null then 1 else 0 end) No_of_records,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M
from cte2 c2
Left Join TEST2 t
on t.Dt between c2.Dts_Start and c2.Dts_end
group by c2.Dts_Start,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M
order by LD_VOY_N, LD_VSL_M, Dts_Start ASC
```

Result:

```
DT                          No_of_records  LD_VOY_N      LD_VSL_M
2017-05-05 16:00:00.000     14             0002W         pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-06 00:00:00.000     14             0002W         pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-06 08:00:00.000     12             0002W         pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-06 16:00:00.000     12             0002W         pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-01 16:00:00.000     1              0007E         omq ynzmeoyn
2017-05-02 00:00:00.000     1              0007E         omq ynzmeoyn
```

It is taking the 8 hour timing as well. Do any of you have any idea why?